# Read and process data in real time

Tags: c#, timer

I'm reading data from the serial port (data is received in chunks) and storing into a buffer. I want to read it and process it in real time without loosing data.

Is a timer the best way to implement it? What happens if the timer elapses before the previous has finished? Does it wait?

```
private void Init()
{
      timerData = new Systems.Timers.Timer;
      timerData.Enabled = true;
      timerData.Interval = 10;
      timerData.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timerReadAndProcessData_Tick);
      timerData.Start();
}

private void timerReadAndProcessData_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (_readAndProcesssDataFlag && Sensor.bufferHasSamples())
    {
       var data = Sensor.getFirstUnprocessedSample(); //buffer.dequeue() in serialPort class
       var parsedData = parse(data);

       for (int i=0; i<parsedData.Length; i++)
       {

          // Process samples here

          // Write processed samples to file
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Systems.Timers.Timer is not thread safe. If you are going to use a Timer, you should use System.Threading.Timer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: What happens if Systems.Timers.Timer elapses when the previous one didn't finished? Does it wait?

Comment: No timer is necessary. You just need a separate thread to loop and listen to the queue in an efficient fashion, e.g. with a synchronization primitive or the `BlockingCollection<T>` class. When done properly the O/S doesn't schedule the thread until there is something in the queue, but otherwise it looks like a continuous loop, and no timer is needed.